# change specific row size of seaborn clustermap

Tags: python, seaborn, cluster-analysis, visualization

I use seaborn clustermap for visualizing clustering results (each row represents a different cluster). In addition, I have the data of what percentage of the total data is assigned to each cluster. I wonder how can I add that information to the clustermap. For example, is it possible to change the clustermap row height in a way that each row with have a height that is proportional to the size of cluster it represents?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the Seaborn documentation and the resulting Matplotlib docs I don't think it is possible via using seaborn. The matplotlib library will allow you to create a pcolormesh (which is what Seaborn uses) in any fashion that you like.

For example, look at the example below. You can specify the x and y values which determine thw height and width of the rows/columns at a given point. As such, with matplotlib you could pass in the width values that you talked about and create your color grid, although the whole process wouldn't be as simple as using `sns.clustermap(iris)`!. See the code below for more info.

```
 # evenly spaced integers
x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])

# uneven spacing between each item
x2 = np.array([1,1.5,3.8,4,5,6])
y2 = np.array([1,1.5,3,4.4,5,6])

# fill with random data
z = np.random.randint(0,32,25).reshape(nrows,ncols)

# create plots
fig, (ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1,figsize=(10,10))

ax1.pcolormesh(x1, y1, z, cmap='Blues', edgecolors='black')
ax2.pcolormesh(x2, y2, z, cmap='Blues', edgecolors='black')
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]